# Are there any free simulators for SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Are there any free simulators available for a hardware design coded in SystemVerilog? In particular, I need SystemVerilog's dynamic arrays.

Comment: In terms of software to simulate it, I can't think of one on the top of my head. [This website](https://www.chipverify.com/systemverilog/systemverilog-dynamic-array) might be able to provide some guidance on viewing your dynamic array, however.

Comment: Vivado is (kind of) free and supports SystemVerilog, though I'm not sure if it supports dynamic arrays. In terms of open source, I doubt it.

Comment: AFAICT, the free simulators (I checked iverilog and verilator) seem to support only synthesizable features of SV, and dynamic arrays wouldn't appear to fall into that classification.

Comment: https://www.edaplayground.com/ provides limited free access to commercial simulators, which may meet your needs

Comment: Are you intending for dynamic arrays to be part of your *hardware* design? They will probably only work as part of your testbench. You're probably already aware, but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 7):

All the versions of Modelsim: Student Edition (SE), the FPGA simulation tools released with Intel Quartus (IE), MicroSemi Libero (ME), and Xilinx Vivado (XE), support all SystemVerilog constructs with the exception of randomize, covergroup, and assertions.

Answer (score 3):

Try the **free** `Modelsim-Intel FPGA edition`:

- https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software/programmable/quartus-prime/model-sim.html

Works great and is closer from what you can find in professional environments.

Select `Standard` and version `16.1` if you don't want to download 6GB. Available for **Linux** and **Windows**.

You might need to create an account to be able to download the file. You can create one for free.

Answer (score 2):

Xilinx Vivado 2020.1 Supports UVM 1.2 and many features of Systemverliog. It supports the same in WebPack (Freeware) Version. I developed a tool "tbengy" to generate a UVM TB and Makefile. You can read the instructions on https://github.com/prasadp4009/tbengy